# How to structure a very small Django Project?

Tags: python, django

It is a little oxymoron now that I am making a small Django project that it is hard to decide how to structure such project.  Before I will at least will have 10 to 100 apps per project.  Now my project is just a website that presents information about a company with no use database, meaning it's really static, with only 10 to 20 pages. Now how do you start, do you create an app for such project.

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with any project that has 100 apps.

Comment: please expand @Daniel

Comment: Frankly it looks like there's been far too much expansion going on already. 100 apps? Who knows how many models? That's not a project, that's a nightmare.

Comment: There are many projects out there that literally have hundreds of apps and breaking them up with that many apps is the only way to avoid chaos.

Answer (score 3):

> meaning it's really static

Use `nginx` to serve static files. Do not use django. You will setup project structure when it will be required.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have static views, you can use the following setup:

- A settings file
- `urls.py`
- `templates/` folder
- `wsgi.py`

You can use a `TemplateView` to direct any url to the appropriate (static) template:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    ...
]
```

Then point the `ROOT_URLCONF` setting to your `urls.py`, and add the `templates/` folder to your `TEMPLATES` setting. Add any other required settings such as `SECRET_KEY` or `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, and configure your `wsgi.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I won't use **Django** in that case, I would use **Flask** for such small projects. it's easy to learn and setup a small website.

**PS: I use Flask in small and large apps!**

Comment: Could you clarify why the size of the project should impact the choice of framework? I'm not sure what advantages either framework would have in case of a small project. If the OP is familiar with Django, why recommend changing to Flask?

Comment: Well personally, it doesn't really matter to me. I just use whatever I like ( which is Flask in this case ) .

Generally, Flask is very suitable for smaller projects. It's very easy and quick to run such a small website out of the box. but for more complex and secured stuff, u need to do the stuff manually.

For instance, it doesn't come with built in csrf protection, unlike Django. but if you want to make csrf protection, just a matter of adding a couple of lines.

<a href="http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/">CSRF Protection in Flask </a>

Comment: Sorry, didn't know notice how to post links.

[link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/)

Comment: Is there any reason why Django is _not_ suitable for smaller projects? Otherwise, this is just an opinion-based "I like this framework better" answer without any arguments to back it up, which doesn't really have a place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I never said it's not suitable, you are asking how to structure such a small application. I replied with you can use Flask, it's easy to learn and setup a small website with it. meaning less structuring problem and can be used right out of the box. then I clarified more that Flask is more suitable that Django because it is small and easy to setup.

Comment: I still don't follow why Flask would be _more_ suitable than Django, or why the size of the framework has any relation to the size of the project for that matter.

Comment: There is no __better__ framework to create smaller projects with, you can use whatever you like. I said you can use Flask for three reasons ( and these are the reasons I use Flask for ):
1 - Flask is very easy to learn, structure and and get it working in a very short time.
2- Flask isn't weak, it can be used for larger applications with extra modules.
3- Flask doesn't force you to a certain module or style, unlike Django which things have to be the way they made it ( Not bad for beginners but I don't like not being free).
Hope that clarifies things.